# How can i format report generated with excel file using jquery or laravel framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, report, reportgenerator

[I have generated this report in excel using jquery
but I want to format this report also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFcNi.png) 
[Is there any Laravel package or any jquery plugin which I can use to convert this file formating into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVHGN.png)

```
   <script>
$(".btn-create-now").click(function(e) {
    $html = $(".table-holding-data").html();
    $("#div_convert_table_into_file table").html($html);
    $("#div_convert_table_into_file table").find("*").removeAttr('class');
    $("#div_convert_table_into_file table").find("*").removeAttr('style');
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#div_convert_table_into_file').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Here is my code of jquery to generate report

Answer (score 0):

**Mattwebsite/excel** is a laravel package used to create excel files. Read documentation of [maatwebsite/excel](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel)

```
   public function downloadExcel()
    {
        $data = Post::get()->toArray();
        return Excel::create('laravelcode', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download('name.xlsx');
    }
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

[TableExport](https://tableexport.travismclarke.com/) The simple, easy-to-implement library to export HTML tables to xlsx, xls, csv, and txt files.

Comment: ok let me go through it

Comment: i want to add formatting to that excel file like I want to add col span I want to add image at top of the excel file with headings with proper formatting.i couldn't,achieve that .and after that I also want to add already created section to that excel file